# How to read and print .iso file using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have a file that extension .iso file and in my file there is 318 bytes of data. so I read data by using following code.

```
byte[]  byteImage = File.ReadAllBytes("F:/FingerData/ISOTemplate.iso");
```

and print the byteImage by using following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < byteImage.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(byteImage[i]);
}
```

but it prints 613 bytes of data.

So please give me a suggestion of code that can print 318 bytes of data.

Comment: .iso is usually for Disk Images. Aka, CD/DVD that is yet to be burned. It has nothing to do with the images you can see on your screen. Nor can you display those kind of images in a console window - it is purely text. Maybe ASCII art. You can of course print out the raw binary or even the content as hex or decimal numbers, but I somewhat doubt that is what you want.

Comment: If it is a fingerprint template, go to page 15 of this document: http://egovstandards.gov.in/sites/default/files/Fingerprint%20Image%20Data%20Standard%20Ver1.0.pdf As for the number of bytes, the file MUST have 613 bytes if the for loop prints out 613 bytes. There is nothing special with the reading of the file with ReadAllBytes(), you are missing something I think.

Comment: It seems like the OP probably have a custom file ext they are using. The question seems to be why the file is 318bytes on disk yet ReadAllBytes is returning an array if length 613

Comment: Dear OP. How do you know your iso file has 318 bytes?

Comment: I have seen in the properties of this file and also for using this code not match fingers

Comment: Thank you for link sir it is not more helpful but thank you for helping me

Comment: Sir, I am recently recovered this data in string and it shows like "07-53-64-23-08-2A-27-31...." and after counting this values it 318 means 07= first byte, 53=second byte and so on

So why it converts to byte[] array to get 318 bytes